# gfortran: Illegal preprocessor directive & Invalid character/non-numeric character compile errors

Tags: compilation, preprocessor, fortran, gfortran, directive

So I'm trying to use the NAS benchmarks for performance testing on a particular MPI implementation.  So I went to compile the fortran code and I'm hitting a barrier.  Whenever I enter this command to compile:

```
gfortran -O0 -Wall -I/home/stephen/trunk/include -I.  -c ./TestData/common/timers.f
```

I get these compiler errors:

```
Warning: mpif.h:2: Illegal pdreprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:3: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:4: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:5: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:6: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:7: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:8: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:9: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:12: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:13: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:14: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:2: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:3: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:4: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:5: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:6: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:7: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:8: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:9: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:12: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:13: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: mpif.h:14: Illegal preprocessor directive
mpif.h:1.1:
    Included at ./TestData/common/timers.f:30:

/*
 1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
mpif.h:1.2:
    Included at ./TestData/common/timers.f:30:

/*
  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
mpif.h:1.1:
    Included at ./TestData/common/timers.f:50:

/*
 1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
mpif.h:1.2:
    Included at ./TestData/common/timers.f:50:

/*
  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
make: *** [cg] Error 1
```

Here is the timers.f code that is erring (lines 30 & 50 are the include lines):

```
c---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                         
c---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                         
      subroutine timer_start(n)
c---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                         
c---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                         
      implicit none
      integer n
      include 'mpif.h'
      double precision start(64), elapsed(64)
      common /tt/ start, elapsed
      start(n) = MPI_Wtime()
      return
      end
c---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                         
c---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                         
      subroutine timer_stop(n)
c---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                         
c---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                         
      implicit none
      integer n
      include 'mpif.h'
      double precision start(64), elapsed(64)
      common /tt/ start, elapsed
      double precision t, now
      now = MPI_Wtime()
      t = now - start(n)
      elapsed(n) = elapsed(n) + t
      return
      end
```

Any ideas?  I have tried all kinds of command line args for gfortran to try and get it to do different types of pre-processing (most of these were done blindly, I do admit).  The weird thing to me is that the compiler is erring on the non-numeric characters /* which are nowhere in my code, so I'm pretty lost.

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing the file suffix you are using from .f to .f90 and the comment line initial character from c to !

Comment: Which MPI implementation are you using?

Comment: Can you post few lines from the beginning of the included `mpif.h`?

Comment: mpif.h looks suspiciously like a C header. You shouldn't ever be importing that in a Fortran source file.

Comment: @talonmies: while I agree with your assertion, it's very common for Fortran MPI programs to `include mpif.h` rather than `use mpi`. mpi-f-for-fortran.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, This is what I got:
mpif.h:22:
    Included at ./TestData/common/timers.f90:50:
C
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

And I checked line 22 of mpif.h and there is nothing out of the usual there.  And line 50 of timers.f90 is the include statement.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark -- http://www.open-mpi.org/papers/euro-pvmmpi-2005-fortran/ -- This huge number of interfaces that need to be generated to create a complete mpi module is probably one reason why a lot of codes still `include 'mpif.h'` instead of `use mpi`

Comment: @mgilson, this was in 2005. Compilers nowadays are much faster. Even if it takes forever to generate all Fortran interfaces, the added argument checking is a _huge_ thing. One of the most common errors that mixed C/Fortran programmers do is to omit the error output argument. If `include 'mpif.h'` is used the compiler will not complain and the program will most likely crash misteriously at runtime. If `use mpi` is used a compilation error would occur. The reason this particular code uses `include` is that it is F77 conformant.

Comment: @HristoIliev -- Yeah, that article is old, but I think the problem still exists (OpenMPI still only generates a partial interface unless told otherwise in `configure`).  I agree that the argument checking is huge though.  I've had a number of programs not crash mysteriously at runtime (just give wrong results) due to errors like the one you described above.  Fortunately, compilers are getting better at diagnosing that sort of error as well.  Also note that `include` isn't standard F77 either -- it wasn't added until F90.

Comment: @mgilson, stictly speaking `implicit none` is also not standard F77 and neither are lowercase letters. But many F77 compilers implemented _almost standard_ extensions that later found their way in the F90 standard. What I wanted to say is that this code is meant to compile even with older pre-F90 compilers. And by the way, omitting the `ierr` in `mpi_init` segfaults Open MPI 1.6 with both `gfortran 4.7` and `ifort 12.1` - fairly recent compilers. Sorry for the off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're definitely compiling this code in a non-standard way.  The usual way to compile f77 or f90 code with mpi is to use the programs **mpif77** or **mpif90** which wrap around the compiler used to build that particular version of MPI.

For example, on my laptop (using OpenMPI compiled with gfortran/gcc), the command `mpif77` is roughly equivalent to:

```
gfortran -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lmpi_f77 -lmpi -lopen-rte -lopen-pal -lutil
```

(I got this information via `mpif90 -showme` -- I don't know if that commandline option is part of the MPI standard so it might not work for you).

to compile your code, I would try something like this:

```
mpif77 -O0 -Wall -c ./TestData/common/timers.f -o timers.o
```

Since there are no other files to be included, it doesn't really make sense to increase you compilers include path using additional `-I` flags -- you just increase the liklihood that you'll accidentally find the wrong header file ;).

Perhaps there's a file 'mpif.h' in either your current directory or in /home/stephen/trunk/include which is getting picked when it shouldn't.  (It looks like you might be seeing a C header since `/*` is the start of a C comment -- although I can't see why a c header file would be called 'mpif.h').

Comment: The options are definitely not MPI standard and are implementation specific.

Comment: -I. and -I/home/stephen/include are both variables in a makefile so when you run "make cg" it ends up looking like what I posted. mpif.h exists in /home/stephen/include so that is why that is there and it is the only file named that on the machine.

Comment: Also, the reason why everything is being done in a non-standard way is b/c the point of the project to create our own version of MPI that allows for redundancy and high failure rates, ultimately for use on BOINC.  I haven't written any of this code, I'm just trying to compile and run it (and go figure the person who did write it, we have lost contact with).  So I don't think mpif77 will work for my problem, but I will try anyway.

Comment: I just found a duplicate mpif.h. So this whole time I was editing the wrong one.  @mgilson, you were correct. Thanks!

Comment: @SteVwonder -- Glad to help.  It makes sense that an mpi implementation would need to be written to have redundancy -- when you have 100000 nodes, I'm sure that the probability that no node fails over the course of an hour drops considerably.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should use mpif77 or mpif90 to link to the right libraries. If gfortran does not like preprocessor macros, you should try -cpp compiler option.

Comment: Adding the -cpp compiler option unfortunately does not seemingly do anything.  Same exact errors as before.

Comment: Yes it couldn't. I didn't realize, that cpp does not process included, but only #included files.